# C# Read an Exported File Excel with OleDb (Always get exception External table is not in the expected format)

Tags: c#, excel, asp.net-mvc, oledb, import-from-excel

I'm Trying read an exported file from my web with Oledb, but always get "**External table is table is not in the expected format**" on code **OleDbConnection.open()** . But when I try copy the values on that excel into new excel, my code is working with that the new one. Its weird right? I must move the values into new excel for read it

This my last code for export excel, I have been tried another code like make excel with htmlwriter and the result always same.

```
   [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult ExportToExcel()
    {ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage();
        ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
        ws.Cells.Style.Font.Size = 11; //Default font size for whole sheet
        ws.Cells.Style.Font.Name = "Calibri"; //Default Font name for whole sheet    
        if (System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.IsRightToLeft)   // Right to Left for Arabic lang
        {
            ExcelWorksheetView wv = ws.View;
            wv.ZoomScale = 100;
            wv.RightToLeft = true;
            ws.PrinterSettings.Orientation = eOrientation.Landscape;
            ws.Cells.AutoFitColumns();
        }
        else
        {
            ExcelWorksheetView wv = ws.View;
            wv.ZoomScale = 100;
            wv.RightToLeft = false;
            ws.PrinterSettings.Orientation = eOrientation.Landscape;
            ws.Cells.AutoFitColumns();
        }
        ws.Cells.AutoFitColumns();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable(); // Read records from database here
        var ReturID = (Int64)Session["ReturID"];
        var Header = ReturService.GetHeader(ReturID, "");
        List<Kino.ViewModel.psa_kino_retur_materialViewModel> test = new List<Kino.ViewModel.psa_kino_retur_materialViewModel>();

        test = ReturService.GetTableRetur(ReturID);
        var v = test.AsQueryable();
        var Data = (from a in v select a).ToList().Select(
             p => new
             {
                 p.material_id,
                 p.material_name,
                 p.delivery_qty,
                 p.sales_unit,
                 p.retur_information
             }
            ); ;

        DataColumn[] cols = { new DataColumn("Material", typeof(string)),

         new DataColumn("Material Name", typeof(string)), new DataColumn("Quantity", typeof(int)),

         new DataColumn("Sales Unit", typeof(string)),new DataColumn("Order Reason", typeof(string)) };
        dt.Columns.AddRange(cols);
        foreach (var item in Data)
        {
            DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
            row[0] = item.material_id;
            row[1] = item.material_name;
            row[2] = item.delivery_qty;
            row[3] = item.sales_unit;
            row[4] = item.retur_information;
            dt.Rows.Add(row);
        }

        ws.Cells[2,1].LoadFromDataTable(dt, true);  // Print headers true          
        ExcelWorksheet ws2 = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet2");
        ExcelWorksheet ws3 = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet3");
        HttpContext.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("", "");
        HttpContext.Response.Charset = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.WebName;
        HttpContext.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8;
        HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=Report.xls");
        HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/text";
        HttpContext.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
        HttpContext.Response.BinaryWrite(pck.GetAsByteArray());
        HttpContext.Response.End();
        return View();}
```

and this my code for read excel

```
  if (postedFile != null)
        {
            string path = Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/");
            if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            }

            filePath = path + Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName);
            string extension = Path.GetExtension(postedFile.FileName);

            postedFile.SaveAs(filePath);

            string conString = string.Empty;
            switch (extension)
            {
                case ".xls": //Excel 97-03.
                    conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel03ConString"].ConnectionString;
                    break;
                case ".xlsx": //Excel 07 and above.
                    conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel07ConString"].ConnectionString;
                    break;
            }

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            conString = string.Format(conString, filePath);

            using (OleDbConnection connExcel = new OleDbConnection(conString))
            {
                using (OleDbCommand cmdExcel = new OleDbCommand())
                {
                    using (OleDbDataAdapter odaExcel = new OleDbDataAdapter())
                    {
                        cmdExcel.Connection = connExcel;

                        //Get the name of First Sheet.
                        try
                        {
                            connExcel.Open();
                        }
                        catch (Exception)
                        {

                            throw;
                        }
                        try
                        {
                            DataTable Count = new DataTable();
                            DataTable dtExcelSchema;
                            dtExcelSchema = connExcel.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                            string sheetName = dtExcelSchema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                            connExcel.Close();

                            //Read Data from First Sheet.
                            connExcel.Open();
                            cmdExcel.CommandText = "SELECT * From [" + sheetName + "]";
                            odaExcel.SelectCommand = cmdExcel;
                            odaExcel.Fill(Count);
                            connExcel.Close();
                            connExcel.Open();
                            int CheckHeader = 2;
                            Boolean Stoplooping = false;

                            foreach (DataRow row in Count.Rows)
                            {
                                foreach (var item in row.ItemArray)
                                {
                                    if (item.ToString()== "Material")
                                    {
                                        Stoplooping = true;
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                                if (Stoplooping==true)
                                {
                                    break;
                                }
                                CheckHeader++;
                            }
                            cmdExcel.CommandText = "SELECT * From [" + sheetName + "A"+CheckHeader+":AA" + (Count.Rows.Count + 1).ToString() + "]";
                            odaExcel.SelectCommand = cmdExcel;
                            odaExcel.Fill(dt);
                            connExcel.Close();
                        }
                        catch (Exception)
                        {

                            ModelState.AddModelError("", "No Data Found");

                        }

                    }
                }
            }
```

this is my connection string for oled db

```
<add name="Excel03ConString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;'" />

<add name="Excel07ConString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=2;'" />
```

Comment: Ole Command has two type a Table mode and a Text mode.  When you copy from one tale to another it uses Table mode.  When you use a select it uses Text mode.  Try following :             cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.TableDirect;
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

Comment: Surely there has to be a better way for transmitting data between systems than preparing an Excel file using EPPlus and then attempting to read it with the ACE driver. Personally, I think the entire concept of what you're trying to do here is flawed.. Why don't you export data from the server in json or xml?

Comment: @CaiusJard thank you for your suggestion but in this chase I must to do that because in this project customer want have excel and than they edit it on site for checking the order,they have habit to use excel for change quantity that want change and they are more confident to use for lot order it

Comment: @jdweng thank you for your information but when I use that code? because the problem is on conn.open(), and i have try place it above conn.open still did'nt work

Comment: Is file xls or xlsx?  If it is xlsx do you either have Microsoft Office installed on PC or installed the ACE driver?  Office comes with ACE so you do not need to install.  But if you are running on PC without Office you need to install ACE.

Comment: @jdweng  I have been try with booth of them for export to try its work or not, actually for reading my solution can read excel with extension xls or xlsx but when I have this chase (Import with the file from export method) my solution can't read

Comment: Can you open the file using excel manually?    You may be saving with wrong extension or the file that got save may be corrupted.  It been a long time since I wrote code like this but setting the CommandType before writing may solve issue.  The worksheet type in the save file has to match the command text.  So make sure when you are writing you are not getting an exception.  Add a try/catch around the write method.

Comment: @jdweng I can open that file and values are same like what I want

Comment: Then you do not have the ACE driver or using a version that isn't installed on your PC.   Make sure you have 12.0 installed (from your connection string) on PC or change version to match what is in your Program Files folder.

Comment: @jdweng, he asserts that if he opens the site-made xlsx and copies the content into a new xlsx saved by excel, then the ace driver works

Comment: I'm suspect the file is automatically getting converted from xlx (open with jet) to xlsx (or xlmx) and getting saved properly.  Then when trying to open xlsx with the wrong version of ACE it fails.

Comment: As an aside the Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 driver will open both types of Excel files. You specify Excel 12.0 even though the .xls files are not this version and the driver sorts it out.